# How to force revalidation of an form?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive, submit

i have a form which holds a couple of fields and an submit button.
To validate a zip code i wrote a directive which calls an API.

```
<input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" zipcodevalidation>
```

To force the valdiation of the form after clicking the submit button is use the 
property in the form tag like so:

```
<form name="form1" id="user-form1" ng-submit="validate" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" novalidate>
```

After clicking the button the directive zipcodevalidation will be executed. 
In case of an invalid zip code the field `zipCode` and the form `form1` are invalid.

If i click again at the submit button, nothing happends!
There is no revalidation taking place.

**Why?**

I need the revalidation taking place without changing the zip code in case of an undefinied error at the API Iam calling.

Help will be very appreciated

Comment: have you tried $setDirty() on the form ?

Comment: Are u talking about setting the whole form in dirty state or the firld in directive like: ctrl.zipCode.$setDirty();

Comment: I just tried it right now with no success.

Comment: Is ng-model-options a valid attribute for ngForm? I haven't seen it documented anywhere.

Comment: I haven't seen it documented too, but it works. 
The workaround for this topic ist to run $validate() to execute manually all pluged in validators. This is not a proper solution at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/FeS4A/58/)

working example but with angular 1.3 version. not supported in 1.2

Hopefully its answers your question

```
<input id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="auth.orderNumber"  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'form.$submitted' }"  ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" required ></input>
```